# Intuition for density formula for Pre-sheaves/Co-Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, yoneda-lemma

I was reading Fosco's [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02503v1.pdf) coend calculus, so far I am at Ninja-Yoneda lemma.

The density formula for pre-sheafs says that,

$${K} V\cong \int^{U\in C} K U\times \textstyle\text{Hom}_{C}(V,U)\cong\displaystyle\int_{U\in C}(K U)^{\textstyle\text{Hom}_{C}(U,V)}.$$
What's the intuitive meaning behind this? I view ends and coends as some sort of averaging over all morphisms in the category, as suggested by Fosco.

The reason for asking this is I need to get a feeling for what is happening, otherwise it remains mysterious as to how someone came up with some random formula like this (which you can prove yes, but then I will have no clue how they got to it)

The proof seems to be to use a chain of isomorphism that lets us sneak in Yoneda lemma.

[image]

The last step seems to be some application Yoneda lemma, but I can't figure it out. I have the following, but not sure how this is $Nat(C(x,-),Sets(K-,y))$. Best I could do is,

$$\textstyle\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sets}}(K V, W)\cong \textstyle\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sets}}\big(\textstyle\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sets}^{{C}^{op}}}(h^V,K ),W\big)
$$

Edit: Skip the last part, I was applying Yoneda to the functor $K$ (Rookie mistake I guess), I should have applied it to $F(-)=\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sets}}(K(-),W)$, which will give me the required,
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sets}}(K(x),W)\cong Nat(h^x,F(-))$$

Comment: read the newest version! they are all full of typos, but slightly less as the version # progresses :)

Comment: @fosco is this what's happening?

When $O(X)^{op}$ is the category of open sets of a space $X$, $Hom_{O(X)^{op}}(U,V)$ is nonempty, only when $V\subseteq U$, in which case its a singleton set, with the inclusion map as the only map. If we consider continuous functions as the pre-sheaf, and $V\subset U$, any 'continuous function' belonging to $U$ will give rise to a 'continuous function' in $V$. Intuitively, we want to include all such functions and it will be a limit in this sense.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove? Yoneda lemma for the category $OX$?

Comment: @fosco No, I was trying to understand what the 'intuitive meaning' of co-yoneda/density formula is. Proof is fine, just a bunch of isomorphisms and yoneda. I wanted an Interpretation of the formula for the pre-sheaf on the category of open sets $O(X)$ of a topological space $X$.

Comment: The intuitive meaning of the density formula for the Yoneda embedding is a discussion too long for a MSE comment: intuitively, it's a procedure of "completion" akin to the one that exhibits $\mathbb R$ as the metric completion of $\mathbb Q$, and this can be made precise, but only with time and a blackboard!

Comment: There is, however, an extremely well-written nLab page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/motivation+for+sheaves%2C+cohomology+and+higher+stacks on a similar topic, with a more geometric perspective that you might like.

Comment: @fosco looks interesting! thanks!

Comment: @fosco Seems to me like the density formula can beintuitively thought of as follows, 

If F is a sheaf of functions the density formula $FU =\int^{V}FV\times Hom(U,V)$ suggests to me that each $FV\times Hom(U,V)$ indicates the collection of functions which can be restricted to $U$ and we want to consider all such functions which can be restricted to $U$. Hence the `integral'.